# Which tables should be emptied when clearing database-stored cache manually?

Tags: 8, caching

Prior to D8 to clear cache manually one could truncate all tables beginning with `cache_`.

In Drupal 8 there are still tables starting with `cache_`, but there's also a `cachetags` table.

Is the advice in D8 still to truncate `cache_*` if you need to clear cache manually? Is it safe/required/recommended to truncate the `cachetags` table along with the `cache_*` tables?

I'm aware there may be contrib modules doing things differently, I'm mostly interested in what core does, and what's considered "best practice" for Drupal 8 in general.

Comment: You can just look at what clear all cache button does.

Comment: ... which is https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!includes!common.inc/function/drupal_flush_all_caches/8.2.x

Comment: All the cache tables are safe for truncating, didn't entirely remove them though.

Answer (score 8):

In drupal 8 if you are looking for the safe tables that needs to be cleared manually then clear the tables starting with cache_   and also truncate the cachetags table too.

If you are using drush then use this command for clear cache-

**drush cache-rebuild**

Answer (score 5):

According to [this article](http://www.sitepoint.com/exploring-cache-api-drupal-8/) `cachetags` are set when cache objects are being stored, so it should be safe to truncate this table also. Cachetags identify cache objects and you can get all related objects at once.

Comment: I tested and the table can be truncated without problems (or only with the potencial performance problem). It is recreated when the entity is loaded but... I don't know why if you delete a entity instance the tags saved in cachetags are already in the table.

I thing that it has to be removed.

Comment: I assume data from cachetags table are removen on cron run and what you see after entity removal are just leftovers

Answer (score 1):

You could do this for a one-liner:

```
drush sqlq "TRUNCATE cache_default;TRUNCATE cache_bootstrap;TRUNCATE cache_container;TRUNCATE cache_discovery;TRUNCATE cache_data;" -l <uri> --no-interaction
```

Add as many with cache_ prefix as you would like.

Answer (score 0):

This is very handy. Replace dbname as needed:

```
DB_NAME="dbname"

mysql -uroot -proot --execute="SELECT concat('TRUNCATE TABLE ', TABLE_NAME, ';') FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '${DB_NAME}' AND TABLE_NAME LIKE '%cache%'" | sed 1d | mysql -uroot -proot ${DB_NAME};
```